Terminal is not opening in Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
Recently I installed Ubuntu 24.04 LTS. It was working well, but suddenly Terminal is not opening. Whenever I click Terminal, It was loading for few seconds then stoped. I changed the language settings several times still not opening. So, I need the solution as soon as possible.
sami@Phone-LP:~/Documents/Odding/CeeSS$ gnome-terminal
bash: /usr/bin/gnome-terminal: cannot execute: required file not found

It shows like this.

What might you have done that you thought changing the language would be of some help?

Could you provide more info? For example, what could have caused the terminal problem (except changing the language)? What applications did you install recently?

Maybe try dafaulting your ~/.bashrc

Recently I installed few files to run python, then i deleted them.  It shows like this, sami@Phone-LP:~/Documents/Odding/CeeSS$ gnome-terminal
bash: /usr/bin/gnome-terminal: cannot execute: required file not found

Try sudo apt install --reinstall gnome-terminal from a TTY or another working terminal (Xterm for example) and maybe for good measure also sudo apt install -f afterwards.

Why is this tagged "server" though? Is this Ubuntu server with a GUI on top? Or what?

I suspect you've messed up your Python installation. Or the /usr/bin/gnome-terminal wrapper script. Do a websearch for "cannot execute: required file not found", you'll get more clues that might be helpful.
